# how to split string in array in java?

Tags: java

i have successfully place the string from file into array. Now i want to split the stringfrom array so that i can create search.
here is the file text patter

file.txt

```
student ID : 1
student name: dell

student id :2
student name:kelly
```

my logic:

1) get the string from file and place in array, that is array[0] contains student ID : 1, a[1] contains student name : dell.

2)now split the current array into further arrays
Now any one please tell me what should i do in order to make array data like this ....

```
array[0] = student ID
array[1] = 1
array[2] =dell
array[3] = student ID
array[4]= 2
array[5] = kelly
.
.
.
```

what should i do in my code???

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.txt")));
String line = br.readLine();
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  
                while(line  != null)
                {

                    list.add(line); // add lines in list
                    line = br.readLine(); // read next line
                }
            //  String[] stringArr= line.split(" : ");
                String [] stringArr= list.toArray(new String[0]);
                list.add(stringArr[0]);
                System.out.println(stringArr[1]);
            //  System.out.print(stringArr[2]);


            }
```

Comment: look at `java.lang.String.split()`

Comment: Since you are looking specifically for info on arrays, this is not an answer, but your design would seem to benefit from using a Map<Integer, String> instead.  Each (key, value) pair is one (id, name)

Comment: i have placed the code. may be you guys now cud give the solution for my problem

Comment: If you use the Scanner class you can use the `useDelimiter()` method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `list.add(line);` inside the while loop with

```
for (String token : line.split(":")) { // Splitting each line with ':'
    if (!token.trim().equals("student name")) { // Adding token to list conditionally.
        list.add(token);
    }
}
```

Then you can easily call `list.toArray()` method to convert the list to array.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks a lot man and to other also for addressing my problem. :)

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

string[] myarray= a[0].split(" : ");

string[] myarray2= a[1].split(": ");

array[0] = myarray[0];

array[1] = myarray[1];

array[2] = myarray2[1];

It should work.

Comment: String [] a = null;
            
             String[] myaray = a[0].split(":"); Givng me error

Comment: ???? any idea or  should paste the code?

Comment: when you edited your question i was writing so i meant the array of the point a in your question

Comment: ooh sorry. i also focus language styles as strictly said by stack form

Comment: Don't worry. it's just that when you added the new code i didn't refresh the page so i didn't read it.

Answer (score 0):

why use two arrays? If your file is a.txt and you want to do this, you only have to use the : as separator char and use a tokenizer, discharging the field student name (the third every 4 tokens):

```
File file=new File("a.txt");
    try {            
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String text="";
        while (scanner.hasNextLine())text+=scanner.nextLine()+":";
        scanner.close();
        StringTokenizer a=new StringTokenizer(text,":");
        List<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=2;a.hasMoreTokens();i++){ //starts from 2 because discharge the third every 4 tokens.
            if(i%4==0)a.nextToken();
            else arr.add(a.nextToken());
        }
        String[] array=(String[])arr.toArray();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope it helps.